# How to disable load *.ts files with SystemJS

Tags: angular, systemjs

I am trying to build my first A2 app using this [guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)

Everything is ok but I receive js and ts files as in the screenshot below:

[image]

1. Is it possible to not load *.ts files?
2. Is it possible to combine vendor files in one? currently App is loading about 40 req.

***config files below:***

**tsconfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**systemjs.config**

```
(function (global) {
  var map = {
    'app': 'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs'
  };
  var packages = {
    'app': { main: 'app.boot', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade'
  ];
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages,
    transpiler: 'none',
    defaultJSExtensions: true
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It's not actually loading the TS files.  Because you are generating the Source Maps, the browser knows how to make the connections, which in turn makes it easier for you developing.

2) I would look at the Ionic framework and mimic a lot of what they do with Browserify.  I'm using it to build out my Frontend.  It consolidates all the JS into one file, and if you tell it to do a release build, minifies and everything.  It uses Gulp, like Madhu said.

Comment: Thanks, as i think before, but need some approve

Answer (score 0):

The quick start guide is just to get you started with basic application.

If you want to use production ready application, you have to invest into creating your Continuous integration package, may be using Gulp\Grunt task runners.

Angular team also has a very nice interface for this named [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/)

Detailed instruction on how to use it can be found [here on Angular CLI Github repo](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)